# Date Diff for different shifts (calculate end time untile shifts time)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Assuming that the shifts are:

```
Morning   06.00 - 13.59
Afternoon 14.00 - 21.59
Night     22.00 - 05.59
```

I posit that I have a dataset called TimesWork and columns start time (with start time of the statement) and end time (with end time of the statement).
I have a column called shift, where I calculated whether the time falls within the morning, afternoon or night shift.

To do this I used this formula, which works

```
Shift = 
IF(
    TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[Start]) >= TIMEVALUE("06:00:00") && TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[End]) <= TIMEVALUE("13:59:59"),
    "Morning",
    IF(
        TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[Start]) >= TIMEVALUE("14:00:00") && TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[End]) <= TIMEVALUE("21:59:59"),
        "Afternoon",
        IF(
            TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[Start]) >= TIMEVALUE("22:00:00") || TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[End]) <= TIMEVALUE("05:59:59"),
            "Night",
            BLANK()
        )
    )
)
```

If start time is from shift A and end time in shift B (e.g. starts in the morning and ends in the afternoon) I created a column that gives me an alert with this formula that works

```
Alert = 
IF(
    (TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[Start]) < TIMEVALUE("13:59") && TIMEVALUE(TimesWork[End]) > TIMEVALUE("14:00")) ||
    (TIMEVALUE(TIMEWORK[Start]) < TIMEVALUE("21:59") && TIMEVALUE(TIMEWORK[End]) > TIMEVALUE("22:00")) ||
    (TIMEVALUE(TIMEWORK[Start]) < TIMEVALUE("05:59") && TIMEVALUE(TIMEWORK[End]) > TIMEVALUE("06:00")),
    "Alert",
    BLANK()
)
```

Now I need to figure out, in case there is an alert, i.e., a row has a start time on one shift (e.g., morning) and an end time on another shift (e.g., afternoon) , how many minutes are from the morning shift and how many are from the afternoon shift. In an example with start time 1:56 p.m. and end time 2:15 p.m. I will have to have a column called "morning times) with the four minutes taken from the row (start time 1:56 p.m. and end of shift at 1:59:59 p.m.) and 15 taken from the row (start time 2:00 p.m. - start of shift and end time 2:15 p.m.) in the column "afternoon times."

How do I do this in powerbi?

Comment: Update your question with a few sample rows of your table in [markdown format](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table), together with what you are expecting/needing.

Comment: Hello. 
I like to have three columns (minute morning / minute afternoon / minute night) where on first colum have different start to 13.59 (if endind time is ove 13.59). On second colum differenct from start to 21.59 (if endind time is over 21.59). On night colum different from start to 05.59 if endind time is over 05.59

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with the following. They are the same except for the `return ...`.
For `Minute Night`, note the `+ 1` to handle midnight cross-over (`+ 1` = add a day).

```
Minute Morning = 
  var twStart = TIMEVALUE([Start])
  var twEnd = TIMEVALUE([End])

  var isMorningStart =   ( TIMEVALUE("06:00") <= twStart && twStart < TIMEVALUE("14:00") )
  var isAfternoonStart = ( TIMEVALUE("14:00") <= twStart && twStart < TIMEVALUE("22:00") )
  var isNightStart =     ( TIMEVALUE("22:00") <= twStart || twStart < TIMEVALUE("06:00") )
  var isMorningEnd =     ( TIMEVALUE("06:00") <= twEnd && twEnd < TIMEVALUE("14:00") )
  var isAfternoonEnd =   ( TIMEVALUE("14:00") <= twEnd && twEnd < TIMEVALUE("22:00") )
  var isNightEnd =       ( TIMEVALUE("22:00") <= twEnd || twEnd < TIMEVALUE("06:00") )

  return SWITCH( TRUE(),
    isNightStart && isMorningEnd, DATEDIFF(TIMEVALUE("06:00"), twEnd, MINUTE),
    isMorningStart && isAfternoonEnd, DATEDIFF(twStart, TIMEVALUE("14:00"), MINUTE)
  )


Minute Afternoon = 
  var twStart = TIMEVALUE([Start])
  var twEnd = TIMEVALUE([End])

  var isMorningStart =   ( TIMEVALUE("06:00") <= twStart && twStart < TIMEVALUE("14:00") )
  var isAfternoonStart = ( TIMEVALUE("14:00") <= twStart && twStart < TIMEVALUE("22:00") )
  var isNightStart =     ( TIMEVALUE("22:00") <= twStart || twStart < TIMEVALUE("06:00") )
  var isMorningEnd =     ( TIMEVALUE("06:00") <= twEnd && twEnd < TIMEVALUE("14:00") )
  var isAfternoonEnd =   ( TIMEVALUE("14:00") <= twEnd && twEnd < TIMEVALUE("22:00") )
  var isNightEnd =       ( TIMEVALUE("22:00") <= twEnd || twEnd < TIMEVALUE("06:00") )

  return SWITCH( TRUE(),
    isMorningStart && isAfternoonEnd, DATEDIFF(TIMEVALUE("14:00"), twEnd, MINUTE),
    isAfternoonStart && isNightEnd, DATEDIFF(twStart, TIMEVALUE("22:00"), MINUTE)
  )


Minute Night = 
  var twStart = TIMEVALUE([Start])
  var twEnd = TIMEVALUE([End])

  var isMorningStart =   ( TIMEVALUE("06:00") <= twStart && twStart < TIMEVALUE("14:00") )
  var isAfternoonStart = ( TIMEVALUE("14:00") <= twStart && twStart < TIMEVALUE("22:00") )
  var isNightStart =     ( TIMEVALUE("22:00") <= twStart || twStart < TIMEVALUE("06:00") )
  var isMorningEnd =     ( TIMEVALUE("06:00") <= twEnd && twEnd < TIMEVALUE("14:00") )
  var isAfternoonEnd =   ( TIMEVALUE("14:00") <= twEnd && twEnd < TIMEVALUE("22:00") )
  var isNightEnd =       ( TIMEVALUE("22:00") <= twEnd || twEnd < TIMEVALUE("06:00") )

  return SWITCH( TRUE(),
    isAfternoonStart && isNightEnd, DATEDIFF(TIMEVALUE("22:00"), twEnd + IF(twEnd < TIMEVALUE("00:00") + 1, 0, 1), MINUTE),
    isNightStart && isMorningEnd, DATEDIFF(twStart, TIMEVALUE("06:00") + IF(twEnd < TIMEVALUE("00:00") + 1, 1, 0), MINUTE)
  )
```